# Logging Servicestack Bad Requests

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to log the validation results which get populated in the ResponseStatus when you have the ValidationFeature plugin enabled?

From what i can understand, any requests coming in get validated and if the validation passes then it goes to the service. Using request filters i can log the requests coming in however using the response filters i can only log valid requests.

I trying to log all responses especially HttpStatus 400 (Bad request) which is returned as a result of a validation error.

I have also tried to play a bit with the RequestLog plugin but from what i understood what gets logged are only valid request (i.e requests that went to the service).

I hope you understand what i am trying to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look to see how [7digital have customized ServiceStack's Validation Feature](http://developer.7digital.com/blog/lessons-learnt-whilst-using-servicestack) to support logging.

### Related Features

The new API supports the concept of a `ServiceRunner` you can override to add your own event and exception hooks you can [read about in the wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api).

There is also the built-in [Request Logger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) that lets you expect details of the more recently processed requests.

Create an [issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues) on the GitHub project if you want to see logging in the validation feature.

Comment: The 7digital link was broken for me, but found it here instead: http://www.antonydenyer.co.uk/blog/2012/09/20/servicestack-the-way-i-like-it/

Comment: FYI anyone who wants to log validation errors, the HandleException method of IServiceRunner does not fire for them.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to log errors from the ValidationFeature plugin is simply thus:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    ...etc...

    Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature() { etc });
    Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature()
    {
        ErrorResponseFilter = MyValidationError
    });

    ...etc...
}

public object MyValidationError(ValidationResult validationResult, object errorDto)
{
    Container.Resolve<IRequestLogger>().Log(null, null, errorDto, TimeSpan.Zero);
    return errorDto;
}
```

However, in my case, I realized that logging validation errors in the service itself is not the proper place; I instead log these errors in the applications that consume the service.